# Represent range value in RealmSwift?

Tags: swift, range, realm

I need to create something like this:

```
import RealmSwift

class UserObject: Object {
  @Persisted var ageRange: ClosedRange<Int>
}
```

But I get error `Generic struct 'Persisted' requires that 'ClosedRange<Int>' conform to '_Persistable'`

How to map `ClosedRange<Int>` to a single object which is supported by realm (without of splitting `ClosedRange<Int>` into 2 Int)?

P.S. note: there are may be similar questions but they are all about the older RealmSwift version which doesn't involve `@Persisted`

Comment: Why don't you want to split `CloseRange` into 2 ints? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Sweeper For example what if `UserObject` has a lot of different ranges, for example age, weight, height and etc.? It will look strange if I write min and max value for each of them instead of wrapping them into another object

Comment: Well, you can write a `RealmIntRange` object that Realm can persist, and in it there are just two ints. I'm not sure if you can make a generic `RealmRange<T>` though, but you can try.

Comment: Tried `RealmRange<T>` but it didn't work, `RealmIntRange` seems to be ok.

Comment: There are other options as well but it's not clear what the use case is. A `UserObject `is a user, and they only have one age e.g. you can't be 50 and 55 at the same time. Why - *It will look strange if I write min and max value for each*? The end user isn't going to see your code, right? lol.  What would look strange about it? Storing min and max values separately is a very common practice. Perhaps if you can share an example, there will be other options. There's nothing wrong with @Sweeper suggestion though, and should actually be an answer.

Comment: @Jay it is rather a wrong class name but it doesn't have influence on this question

Comment: Understood. Just wanted to clarify what was being asked in case the answer needed to be adjusted. Looks go though and it seems you have an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than a little bit of code duplication, I really don't see what "looks strange" about splitting the range into 2 `Int`s.

If you want to avoid code duplication when there are multiple such pairs of properties, you can write an `RealmIntRange` Realm object that is persistable.

```
class RealmIntRange: Object {
    @Persisted var min: Int = 0
    @Persisted var max: Int = 0
}
```

Then in `UserObject`,

```
@Persisted var ageRange: RealmIntRange?
```

Unfortunately this has to be an optional type.

Comment: There may be a background reason but why *Unfortunately this has to be an optional type.*? We have a number of projects that use that exact model and are not optional. Obviously we force the values to always be populated if we use them but this `@Persisted var ageRange: RealmIntRange!` is perfectly valid (from our usage). In face we do this `@Persisted var ageRangesList = RealmSwift.List<RealmIntRange>()` all the time

Comment: @Jay Maybe "unfortunate" is too strong of a word... Maybe it' just me, but I just don't like having optional-typed properties when semantically they are not optional (not sure if that is the case *here*, but there could be such situations). `RealmIntRange!` is valid, but it's still an optional type, and can still have `nil` as a value.

Comment: Ah, I see that point. In the Swift SDK, non-optionals cannot be nilled e.g. `var i = RealmIntRange()` and then `i = nil` will throw an error `'nil' cannot be assigned to type 'RealmIntRange'`. However, if an object contains a `RealmIntRange` property, and it's written, that property is set to null, and can be checked for nil. Kind of an odd case. Thanks for the explanation.